# Vertically center text of an anchor with fluid height

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm trying to achieve this implementation:

[image]

The container is `height: 100%` and the `li` are `height: 50%` each one. The link is 50% height and the entire colored area should be clickable.
This is my code:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.menu {
    height: 100%;

    ul {
        height: 100%;

        li {
            height: 50%;

            a {
                display: block;
                height: 100%;
                line-height: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the `line-height` trick doesn't work. The height of the window is obviously fluid because it should be responsive on every device. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `line-height: 50%` on a `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use something like position relative and absolute to achieve this.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.menu {height: 100%;}
.menu ul {
        height: 100%;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
}
 .menu ul li {
            height: 50%;
            width:100%;
            display:table;
}

.menu ul li a {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qsHw2/2/

Comment: The entire area of the `li` should be clickable. Hence the `a` elements needs to be bigger as the entire `li`. Doesn't work in this way.

Comment: I have edited the post and updated the fiddle. now the whole li is clickable!

Answer (score 0):

What if you just do this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/SBag9/2/

```
.menu {

height: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
margin-top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I need a good browser support and flex stuff doesn't seems to be very supported.